# Unexplained heroku timeouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails 3.2.11 app deployed on Heroku that has been fairly stable over time. In the last 24 hours, pingdom has been reporting Timeouts which I can't find any "H1X" related errors in the logs at the same time.

I am occassionally able to reproduce the timeouts in google chrome. where I would get this message after about 30 seconds of requesting any page:

Chrome browser error
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

The app will then begin serving requests normally until it happens again.

I know this is not enough info, but I can't find anything useful yet in newrelic or scanning the logs that correlates to when the error occured.

In one instance, i was reproducing the error in the browser while viewing the heroku logs and when the timeout occurred, there was no evidence of the request showing up in the logs. Its like the failed requests never make it into the app.

Comment: In case you're not already aware of it, you can check https://status.heroku.com, though I don't see anything for the current day

Comment: Nothing is reported. And heroku support is off for the weekend.

Comment: Heroku support is always around, but less active at weekends

Comment: My urgent production ticket has been un-responded to for the past 26 hours. and The message says I should not expect a response until the next business day.. about 32 hours from now.

Comment: @koa how did you resolve this issue?